# Drag to Resize a Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

### My Live Page:

http://rafflebananza.com/Admin/Desktop/index123.html#

### JQuery I Use:

- jquery-1.11.0.min.js
- jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
- jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js

### The Problem:

I would like to make my Quick-Sidebar, the sidebar you see to the right-hand side with the three tabs, have a drag-able width. I have tried several attempts without success;

**Code Attempt:**

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').resizable({
    handles: 'w'
});
```

Although I have seen this work such as this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YZX6B/12/), implementing this onto my site doesn't seem to work and updating to a more recent JQuery does not seem to work with all of my coding.

### Question

How can I make my side menu resizeable on drag, dynamic fluid drag and if using JQuery I wish to do this using minimal JQuery css.

Comment: you have not called `$('.Quick-Sidebar').resizable();` anywhere in your script, then how could you expect it working?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I removed this prior updating the server. I've just reupdated my server with this code on lines 491-493.

Comment: Someone left a comment saying update to jquery ui 1.11.4 so I just did and now my other side bar to the left breaks when you click the minimize button so I am reverting back to 1.10.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ribumoweho/edit?html,css,output)

Your resizable needs to be in a wrapper.

In my case `.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper`

The wrapper needs the same width as the starting sidebar width (322px)

```
.Quick-Sidebar-Wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
    float:right;
    width: 322px;
}

.Quick-Sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 100%;
    outline: 1px solid #ccc;
    overflow:hidden;
    cursor: default;
}
```

You haven't included the jquery-ui css so add some custom style for the `.ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w`. That's the helper div you'll use to resize the sidebar.

```
.ui-resizable-w{
  height:100%;
  width:5px;
  background:limegreen;
  cursor: w-resize;
}
```

Run the plugin using this:

```
$('.Quick-Sidebar').resizable({
  handles: 'w'
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much. A fantastic answer along with a live demo! Thank you once again :)